# Connect a Garmin and fetch GPS stream

Tags: gps, garmin

I own a Garmin Oregon 600. I know that it has some communication capabilities, but I have not found on user guide how to use it. Does anyone of you know how to connect this device by USB/Serial in order to fetch its stream of data? I am confident with data stream and serial communication. I just have not found how to setup my device in order to turn it as a recognizable COM device and make it stream its data. I use windows and linux indifferently.

Answer (score 1):

you can find user manuals here http://support.garmin.com/support/manuals/manuals.htm?partNo=010-01066-00&language=en&country=US

Plus following link gives you the applications that you can use with garmin and different versions of arcmap: http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/DNRGPS/DNRGPS.html